# How to grouping dictionary keys by value in json

Tags: python, json

I have this json file which has some data like this:

```
[
    {
        "stats": [
            {
                "city": "'s",
                "latitude": "51",
                "longitude": "5",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_all_time",

            },
            {
                "city": "'s",
                "latitude": "5",
                "longitude": "5.67",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.03",
                "longitude": "9.007",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_all_time",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.033",
                "longitude": "9.0007",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.0",
                "longitude": "9.97",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_month",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aarau",
                "latitude": "47.32",
                "longitude": "8.05",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
```

And I want to group all the Date Range which has same value say "date_range": "date_last_year". I was trying this code but when I try to print the values, its showing like this "The filtered dictionary is : {}". 
Please help me, I'm just a beginner to learn json and python. Thank you

```
def convert_object():        
    res = dict((k, finaljson[k]) for k in ['Date_Range']
               if k in finaljson)

    print("The filtered dictionary is : " + str(res))

The Actual result/Outpu I want is like this, all date_last_year values:

            {
                "city": "'s",
                "latitude": "51",
                "longitude": "5",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "'s",
                "latitude": "5",
                "longitude": "5.67",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.03",
                "longitude": "9.007",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.033",
                "longitude": "9.0007",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aalborg",
                "latitude": "57.0",
                "longitude": "9.97",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
            {
                "city": "Aarau",
                "latitude": "47.32",
                "longitude": "8.05",
                "region": "Europe",
                "date_range": "date_last_year",

            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have "data" as a list with your data.

```
final_json = dict()
for obj in data:
    if obj['date_range'] in final_json:
        final_json[obj['date_range']].append(obj)
    else:
        final_json[obj['date_range']] = [obj]

import json
print(json.dumps(final_json, indent=4))
```

Comment: Hi @newbie, thanks for replying. As I'm using your logic, I'm getting empty value in print statement; like this {}

Comment: you might be missing out something. It is straight-forward logic. I have tried it and it is working. Did you assign your list to "data"?

Answer (score 0):

This of json as a nested dictionary where each level is an indice.